# Get class by function parameter in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to call a class by its name as a parameter in function. I have the variable `val1` that holds the class name:

```
var val1 = "aaa";
```

I have this div that his class name is `aaa` and it contains an onclick event that call `playAction` function:

```
<div class='aaa' onclick='playAction(val1)' ></div>
```

I have the next function:

```
function playAction(val2) {

    $(val2).hide()
}
```

How can I call the parameter `val2` in the function and hide the class by its name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try: (class select starts with `.`)
`$("."+ val2).hide()`

Or call your function like:

`playAction('.' + val1);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.` selector

```
var val1 = "aaa";

function playAction(val2) {
  $("." + val2).hide()
}
```

But I would suggest you to use jquery event binding instead of inline binding.

```
<div class='aaa clickableDiv' ></div>
```

then jquery code will be,

```
$(".clickableDiv").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("aaa")) {
    //do your stuff here
    $(this).hide();
  }
})
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/198/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery selector:

```
$("."+ val2).hide()
```

BTW, if you are already use jQuery, consider the following:

```
$(".aaa").click(function(event) {
    $(event.target).hide();
});
```